# Set context menu over HERE map

Tags: javascript, html, here-api

Is it possible to set something like context menu or spoiler over map, using HERE?
If you know, how to do it, please, let me know,i'll appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for a 'contextmenu' event on the map instance. Here is an example:

```
map.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (evt) {
  evt.items.push(new H.util.ContextItem({
    label: 'Zoom in',
    callback: function () {
      map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
    }
  }));
});
```

Comment: i did it, and nothing happened

Comment: Maybe because your map doesn't create the default UI components. Do you load `mapsjs-ui.js`, call `H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);` and see the default zoom control? Can you edit the question and add the map initialization code?